# Keep getting an Indexerror, trying to work with chararrays

Tags: arrays, python-3.x

I am currently working on a simulation of sorts, and I have code that constructs data into an array like so:

```
[['_' '_' 'F' '_' '_']
 ['_' '_' '_' '_' '_']
 ['W' '_' '_' '_' 'J']
 ['_' '_' '_' '_' '_']
 ['_' '_' 'G' '_' '_']]
```

where I'm stuck is I don't quite know how to create an orthoganal step by step spread of data if that makes sense.

Basically what I'm trying to do is step-wise change the values in my chararray so it looks more like this:

```
[['_' 'F' 'F' 'F' '_']
 ['W' '_' 'F' '_' 'J']
 ['W' 'W' '_' 'J' 'J']
 ['W' '_' 'G' '_' 'J']
 ['_' 'G' 'G' 'G' '_']]
```

after step 1, and then that continues for step 2 etc etc until there is no more room for any movement.

My idea was to create a list, of everything that surrounded it orthogonally  and use that list to determine what '_' was supposed to change into. However when I ran the code **IndexError: index 4 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 4.** I don't quite understand what I'm doing wrong or how to fix my code so it works a bit better. Here the bit of my code that seems to be causing the error after running it line by line:

```
def spring_spreading(farm):
    for pos_x in range(len(farm)):
        for pos_y in range(len(farm)):
            neighbors = []
            if farm[pos_x, pos_y] == '_':
                if farm[pos_x + 1, pos_y] != '_':
                    neighbors.append(farm[(pos_x + 1, pos_y)])
                    print (neighbors)
```

Answer (score 0):

This line is causing the error, `if farm[pos_x + 1, pos_y] != '_':`. Note that your loop goes from `0` to `len(farm)` and indexes starts always in zero. Note also that the length of the second dimension may change. A proper iteration would be:

```
for i in range(len(farm)):
    for j in range(len(farm[i])):
        # whatever
```

Note also that the matrix you posted has no commas.

Comment: I took what I had from my console, and when I have an array there, there are no commas